# Supermicro server hangs on boot with disks in HBA

Tags: boot, dell, sas, truenas, supermicro

I have a "homemade" Supermicro server with an X9D board in an 836 chassis that has two SSDs with freenas installed. It has a pass-through backplane, with 4 SATA HDDs running via the Intel C606 motherboard controller and a SFF-8087 to 4 SATA cable attaching to the backplane. This was working very well with no issues.

To add more storage I recently added a Dell HBA330+ SAS3 HBA. It has Dell IT-mode firmware. The system booted into freenas just fine after installing it, still no signs of trouble.

I purchased some 10TB SAS3 seagate enterprise drives, and installed them into the system (already running). They were detected immediately and I was able to see them in freenas, run SMART tests, etc.

I then made some changes to freenas, and rebooted the system, and.... waited and waited, after checking that the web console was still not up, I checked the machine. It was stuck on the Supermicro logo screen (with B2) in the corner.

I rebooted with a monitor directly attached, it did the normal thing, powers on, supermicro splash, going through the boot menus for the Dell HBA330+, 10g network card, and the disks on the C606. Then it hangs on the supermicro logo before loading the OS. It also freezes in the same place if I try to invoke the [del] or [f11] boot/startup menus. HOWEVER, if I pull the new disks, it will boot cleanly. Anyone have any ideas on how to fix the issue?

Comment: I would consider updating the board's and HBA's firmwares, disabling the HBA330's boot ROM invocation in BIOS setup and asking Supermicro's support about the issue - in this order.

Comment: This really falls outside of the production ServerFault mandate because it isn't something any reasonable server manager would try to put into business production.